# Doctrine 2 Command-line on standalone project

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am a little bit confused as to what I need to do to make Doctrine 2 Command-line work in a stadnalone application.

I have manaed to get it to work with accessing the database but my problem is that I would like to be able to interact with the database server via its command-line tool.

[Here](https://luyandasiko.wordpress.com/) is an article I wrote about seting up doctrine but the command-line functionality I have no idea how its setup I always stumble across cli-config.php file but this doesn't help.

Could someone please give me pointers? I am on windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Ok a quick update:

I have managed to get my Doctrine Command-line application working. Reading these google [docs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/doctrine-user/_ph183Kh-5o/_P_coljB-dcJ) helped a lot. Basically what I needed to do was to run my commands like this:

```
cd root_dir
root_dir>vendor\bin\doctrine.bat
```

Instead of the command I have always been using **vendor/bin/doctrine**.

The second issue I faced was:

> Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\ConsoleRunner::run() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet, integer given,

And I found a solution here within [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131662/doctrine-orm-cli-tool-not-working) below are is what I had and what I updated my cli-config.php file to.

```
//Version: mine
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

//Version: theirs
$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

return $helperSet;
```

I am going to challenge myself by trying to use Doctrine without the cli-config.php file as I am wanting to take advantage of Object Oriented Programming.